# behaviour subject is updated after the component initiates

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 14 and have a loader service that utilizes a BehaviorSubject (showSpinner) to control the visibility of a spinner:

```
show() {
  if (!this.showSpinner.value)
    this.showSpinner.next(true);
}
```

However, when I attempt to use this service in my component, the spinner isn't displayed until I reload the page.
I invoke it within ngOnInit() before calling a service to fetch data:

```
this.loaderService.show();
this.followUpExamRegService.GetSecondarySchoolsRegistStatus(this.selectedSchool.stageTypeCode).subscribe(data => {
  this.loaderService.hide();
  this.SecondarySchoolsRegistStatus = data;
});
```

Additionally, I encounter a console error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'". Strangely, if I navigate using href instead of routerLink, everything works fine without errors.

I suspect the issue arises because the subject isn't updated before navigation, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Some suggest using setTimeout, but I believe this isn't a proper solution. Can you advise on how to address this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can u add more code ? like ,How you are intializing spinner etc.Show codes in the loaderService pls